# Inequality $\left(\frac {17}{25}\right)^k \le 10^{-5}$ - Solve for $k$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

How can I solve for $k$ the following inequality :

$$ \left(\frac {17}{25}\right)^k \le 10^{-5} $$

This is what I got so far. By taking $\log_k$ from both sides I get:

$$ \log_k{\left(\frac {17}{25}\right)^k} \le \log_k{10^{-5}} $$

How can I continue from here?

Comment: Maybe it's better to use $\log_{17/25}$?

Comment: So I would get : $ k \le log_\frac{17}{25} {10^{-5}}$ ?

Comment: Just use ln.  ln(17/25)^k = k*ln(17/25).  then divide by ln(17/25).  k=ln(10^-5)/ln(17/25)

Comment: Nop. Don't forget $17/25<1$

Comment: Understood.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the natural logarithm instead:
$$
k \ln \frac{17}{25} \leq -5\ln 10
$$
Note that $\ln \frac{17}{25} < 0$ since $\frac{17}{25} < 1$, so by dividing both sides you'll get the equivalent inequality
$$
k \geq -5\frac{\ln 10}{\ln \frac{17}{25}} = 5 \frac{\ln 10}{\ln \frac{25}{17}} = 5\log_{\frac{25}{17}} 10.
$$
(where the inequality has been flipped, since as noted above we divide both sides by a negative number).

Answer (score 1):

$$
{ \left( \frac { 17 }{ 25 }  \right)  }^{ k }\le { 10 }^{ -5 }\\ k\ln { \left( \frac { 17 }{ 25 }  \right)  } \le -5\ln { (10) } \\ k\ln { \left( \frac { 25 }{ 17 }  \right)  } \ge 5\ln { (10) } \\ k\ge \frac { 5\ln { (10) }  }{ \ln { \left( \frac { 25 }{ 17 }  \right)  }  } \\ k\ge 29.85
$$

Answer (score 1):

Take the natural log of both sides; you have
$$-k \log(25/17)=k\log(17/25) \le -5 \log(10).$$
Divide and get
$$k \ge {5\log(10)\over\log(25/17) }$$

Comment: `log` usually denotes the decimal log.

Comment: @Bernard This is not actually that obvious, and heavily depends on the convention of the particular field. (See [e.g. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases): $\log$ can basically mean any of the three "common bases"). Wolfram Alpha, as an example, [uses $\log$ for the natural logarithm](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28e%29), $\ln$; computer scientists use $\log$ for the binary logarithm, $\log_2$... it's all a matter of convention.

Comment: @ClementC. And it doen't matter in this case since  $\dfrac{\log(x)}{\log(y)} = \dfrac{ln(x)}{ln(y)} = \dfrac{lg(x)}{lg(y)}$

Comment: @StevenGregory Indeed...